# How to fix Cross Site Scripting security warning in rails generated by brakeman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I used brakeman for generating scanning reports in my application. It generated many Cross Site Scripting security warnings with High Confidence.
In that one of them is:

```
Unescaped parameter value rendered inline near line 47: render(text => "Unexpected EventType #{params["EventType"]}", { :status => 406 })
app/controllers/event_controller.rb.
```

In the controller method shown below, the 1st line is showing the above warning.

I have seen in the [link](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/cross_site_scripting/) but couldn't fix. Please help.
And this is controller code:

```
  def purchase

    render :status => 406, :text => "Unexpected EventType #{params['EventType']}" and return unless params['EventType'] == 'purchased'
    @account = Account.new
    render :status => 406, :text => "Could not find Plan #{params['Plan']}" and return unless @account.plan = @plan = SubscriptionPlan.find_by_name(params['Plan'])

  end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `render :text => ...` Rails still renders the output as HTML (with content type `text/html`). Since your code is putting user input (`params['EventType']`) directly in the output, this is a classic cross-site scripting vulnerability.

You have two options. Use `render :plain` instead (which will render with content type `text/plain` instead of HTML):

```
render :status => 406, :plain => "Unexpected EventType #{params['EventType']}"
```

or escape the user input:

```
render :status => 406, :text => "Unexpected EventType #{ERB::Util.html_escape(params['EventType'])}"
```